# Put a conditional format conversion in a sequence of piped Shell commands

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, pipe

How is it possible to add an optional

```
iconv -f utf-16 -t latin1
```

inside a sequence of piped commands?

The assumption is that the source file can be either in latin1 or in utf16.

Shell scripts using awk, grep and the like should be able to work on both formats, by adding an optional conversion step.

How could that be done in the most beautiful manner, while respecting the DRY principle (not repeating the other commands)?

EDITED --

Curent sequence of commands looks like:

```
awk '...' $1 | cut ... | colorize
```

Comment: What do you mean "an optional". Are you looking for an If statement? What does your sequence of piped commands look like?

Comment: Yes, looking at some sort of if statement, so that $1 is first converted to latin when it's utf-16. Would like to avoid temp files, and simply have (if possible) one extra step in the sequence of commands.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly efficient, but the following easily sets up conditional commands within a pipeline. The trick is to select from various alternate commands so you always run *something:*

```
opt_condtion=true;    #true run extra command, false not to

first_command | ( $opt_condition && ( optional_command || true ) || cat ) | third_command
```

The `( optional_command || true )` assures the **cat** does not run if *optional_command* returns a non-zero exit code as an extra **cat** would likely hang the pipelined command.

Using full (subshells) allows you a lot of freedom. If the commands get too complex put them in a function to keep the pipeline simple.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, here is (more or less) my command: `tail -f ${1} | ( [[ $(file -i ${1}) =~ utf-16be ]] && ( iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 || true ) || cat ) | awk '...' | cut ... | colorize`